# Flexboxes: stacked, centered, wrapping, with color-matching sides and dynamic, synchronized width (see example)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

Basically, I want something that acts similar to the following snippet. Notice how adding an item to one flex row increases the width of both.

```js
function initItems() {
    const numArr = Array.from(Array(3).keys());
  const items = numArr.map(() => "item");
  return items;
}

function FlexItems() {
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState(initItems);
  const addItem = () => setItems([...items, "item"]);
  
  return (
    <div className="flex-row">
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
      {items.map((item, idx)=><div className="item" key={idx}>{item}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}

function StackedCenteredFlexItems() {
    return (
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td className="side first">.</td>
    <td className="center first"><FlexItems/></td>
    <td className="side first">.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td className="side second">.</td>
    <td className="center second"><FlexItems/></td>
    <td className="side second">.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StackedCenteredFlexItems />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.center {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td.side {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1px;
  color: transparent;
}

.first {
   background: lightblue;
}

.second {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

This solution is close, the active ingredient being that the flex rows are in the center cells of a table with this applied:

```css
td.center {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

In that example flex-wrap is set to nowrap, however, because with wrap turned on, all the items in the flex rows just stack on top of one another. But I need the items to wrap in response to window size, like this:

```js
function initItems() {
    const numArr = Array.from(Array(20).keys());
  const items = numArr.map(() => "item");
  return items;
}

function FlexItems({ className }) {
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState(initItems);
  const addItem = () => setItems([...items, "item"]);
  
  return (
    <div className={"flex-row " + className}>
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
      {items.map((item, idx)=><div className="item" key={idx}>{item}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <FlexItems className="first" />
    <FlexItems className="second" />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.first {
   background: lightblue;
}

.second {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

The first example has most of what I want:

- The flex rows are centered in the window
- When an item is added to one flex row, the width of both increases
- To the left and right of each flex row, the background matches the flex row's color

The second example has the other thing:

- Flex wrap responds to the edges of the window

How can I get all of it?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Also applying flexbox to a table is not ideal. They have different styles by default that may conflict.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm happy to go with a solution that doesn't involve a table.

Comment: @Paulie_D Just replaced the links with stack snippets.

Answer (score 1):

**You just need to remove `width` from td and `justify-content: center` to the `flex-row` class;**

Final solution: https://jsfiddle.net/s1gu8L4t/

Comment: That's close, but in that example the widths of the flex rows are no longer synchronized—adding an item to one doesn't increase the width of the other.

Comment: I don't get it? What exactly is `increase the width of the other`?

Comment: Adding an item in one should increase the width of both. Click one of the add item buttons in this example to see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/68z5v1aq/

Comment: I feel like there is a person, just trying to give negative feedback to my answer, is this a personal attack?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't mean to sound like I'm attacking you. I really do need help with this! In your example, clicking one of the "add item" buttons increases the width of the flex-row that gets the new item. But I need both of the flex rows to increase in width when a new item is added. To see what I mean, make sure your window is wide enough for all of the items to fit on one row, and then click "Add Item".

Comment: I see, It was not meant for you, There is a person who just try to follow my post and downvote them. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I was not talking to you.

Comment: You can see that that person also downvote your original question too.